# one index.php to handle everything

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am currently working on developing mini cms in php for little projects.
First of all, let me say that I have just basic knowledge about that language.

While trying to develop login page for that mini cms, i have searched for projects at github and encountered with project called "[php-login-minimal](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal)".

I had implemented it according to my project but i have some troubles as follows;

it uses views and protects that views from external access with .htaccess which includes below commands;

```
# This file prevents that your .php view files are accessed directly from the outside
<Files ~ "\.(htaccess|php)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

And calls that views if user is logged in like that;

```
// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    // the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
    include("views/logged_in.php");
} else {
    // the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

The trouble starts here.
In the "**logged_in.php**" file of my project, there are navigation links which redirects user to that views to create, update page or posts like follows;

```
<li class="active">
 <a href="<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT; ?>index.php">main panel</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT; >page/pageManagement.php">pages</a>
 <ul>
  <li class="green"><a href='<?php echo ADMIN_ROOT; ?>page/createPage.php'>create new page</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

So, as it is expected, when i click to that links, it shows me forbidden message. How can i deal with this problem or can you lead me to better solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you looking to block access to backend PHP files?. I'm also working on a webpage where you're always on the index and javascript handles the content, but as long as you're not linking any of those PHP scripts you shouldn't really want to block them, normal users won't try to access them and whoever does should just deal with whatever problems it causes for him. You should make it so that even if it's directly accessed it can't do any harm.

Comment: @aron9forever infact i also want to understand it. Why the developer preferred developing the project in the way that. He argues that, in the modern web development, projects uses one index.php to handle everything. source: [http://www.dev-metal.com/install-php-login-nets-1-minimal-login-script-ubuntu/#comment-1061061745]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution is an opinion...

But there are valid arguments to prevent direct access to `.php` code:

**Clean URL coherence:**

By preventing direct access, you guarantee that your site url scheme will be respected, avoiding different ways to accessing your pages.

**URL longevity:**

Your URLs are not directly connected to your file structure, so you can maintain it even if you change site structure or programming language.

**Security:**

Not all your php files are necessarily intended to be loaded by URL, some of these are intended to be included in other php files. Another way to prevent direct access to these pages is to declare a global variable in parent file and — in include file — stopping execution if that variable is undefined.

---

The use of one page to route all requests is another common practice, that has advantage of simplify RewriteRule conditions and clean control all your redirects in one page of code. In a sense, it is a first step to more complex [architectural patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern). I see that your 3rd part script includes 'views/...': probably it refers to MVC pattern.

So, if you choose to maintain your original URL structure, you have to remove the .htaccess file, otherwise you have to rewrite your URLs and modify the .htaccess file adding RewriteRule conditions redirecting to your index.php (or another router filename) .